# automated tax calculations using stripe in django python

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am new to django python and I want to calculate tax on checkout page when customer add shipping address automatically using strip on billing address in python django

i found below code but i don't know how to integrate this code

```
stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'

stripe.Plan.create(
  nickname="Car Wash Volume Pricing",
  product="{{CAR_WASH_PRODUCT_ID}}",
  currency="usd",
  interval="month",
  usage_type="metered",
  billing_scheme="tiered",
  tiers_mode="volume"
  tiers=[
    {
      "amount": 700,
      "up_to": "5",
    },{
      "amount": 650,
      "up_to": "10",
    },{
      "amount": 600,
      "up_to": "inf",
    },
  ]
)
```

Comment: what have you try post some code

Comment: i was update my post